# Function reassignment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, higher-order-functions

I Have a function written in javascript which traces recursion calls of a function passed to it.

```js
function trace(fn){
    let indent = 0

    return function tracedFunction(args){
        console.log("| ".repeat(indent)+"|--"+fn.name,args)
        indent += 1
        let value = fn(args)
        console.log("| ".repeat(indent)+"|--"+"return",value)
        indent -= 1
        return value
    }

}

function fibo(num){
    if(num==0 || num==1)
        return 1;
    return fibo(num-1)+fibo(num-2);
}


fibo = trace(fibo)
fibo(4)
```

This gives the following output

```
|--fibo 4
| |--fibo 3
| | |--fibo 2
| | | |--fibo 1
| | | | |--return 1
| | | |--fibo 0
| | | | |--return 1
| | | |--return 2
| | |--fibo 1
| | | |--return 1
| | |--return 3
| |--fibo 2
| | |--fibo 1
| | | |--return 1
| | |--fibo 0
| | | |--return 1
| | |--return 2
| |--return 5
5
```

#### My Questions are the following

1. What is happening in the line `fibo = trace(fibo)` ?

   - A is it redefining the `fibo` function?
   - B is it creating a variable in global scope called `fibo` and assigning `trace(fibo)` to it?
   - if (A) is the case, is it a good practice to do so? Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: It is simply assigning a value to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is called a "decorator". This is a very common and widely used feature in python, but in JS, after some 5 years of work, they are still in the queue. Transpilers and TypeScript do support decorators, but still it's not possible to decorate a function, only a method, so you have to wrap your `fibo` in a class for this to work (which looks quite silly if you ask me):

```
function trace(target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
    let indent = 0;
    let fn = target[propertyKey];

    descriptor.value = function tracedFunction(args){
       etc
     }
}

class Dummy {
    @trace
    static fibo(num) {
        if (num == 0 || num == 1)
            return 1;
        return Dummy.fibo(num - 1) + Dummy.fibo(num - 2);
    }
}

Dummy.fibo(4)
```

[Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?noImplicitAny=false&experimentalDecorators=true&ssl=25&ssc=14&pln=16&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFATgQwgUwBRTSgc0ygBpEAHFOczFKATwGlN6yATTAZwhRnKjgoAlIgDeAKERTEAG2KIYYDmCiIAvIgAMAbknS5q4Eg15CxANqVqtBs3oBdXXqkduvfoIB0ANzQyQmOqIoJCwCMjoWGwAYuDQ8GDY+AScQhLSGYgQCJxwcp4ycATYAEQAPoglniiYNGhQ2IrKUEIA1OUAtB0lrUaeYGgAtpgkyanOmU2YKoitGgCMExkGiL7+gRpGSYTjmdLZYLn5hcXlldW1mPWNStMt7WVdPSU1UCAoYCUkawFCS9JTGYdBb-KSvd5IH6YCYAX3E4jh4ggMjQnE4iAAIiBBoN6GIJgABVAYaEZTh4WAQYIwABGcGwYGxInSewUwEQDOx6g0mkQZQqjMG3MQ8z+rMy4I+It04slSCxOPonmAtPpgsQHRFIlamOxuOVqs5Qs1ACYhDLpHDEQr9Sq6dgACxCIA)

Until the decorator syntax is standardized and properly implemented, the only way to decorate a function is how you wrote it - apply a decorator and reassign to the original name.

To answer your questions, it's both A and B -- functions are first class in javascript, so assigning a function value to a variable binds that variable to that function and the old function is lost. Function declaration syntax `function foo() {...}` is basically just a shortcut for `var foo = function ....` (up to some nasty hoisting details).

Comment: Hi, this makes sense now. I had thought that reassigning function was a bad practice. Is there any way to include this logic `fibo = trace(fibo)` in the `trace` function itself .

Comment: @AlanLal: in general, no, you can't. That's one reason why decorators are only possible for object methods, not functions.